# What part of Chult does this image depict?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, tomb-of-annihilation, art

What part of Chult does this image depict?

[image]

It is found in Tomb of Annihilation, on page 9. Is it Aldani Basin?

> The Soshenstar and Tath rivers flow out of this marshy upland basin, which is a popular feeding ground for dinosaurs and swarms of biting insects. Tall plateaus and walls of dense foliage enclose the marsh.

The description matches, but the image is not labeled, and is on a different chapter of the book.

Comment: That's a post card from the Chultan tourist bureau.  No actual place in Chult looks like that. 8^D  Travel brochure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the artwork was originally intended to be near Omu (possibly near the waterfall section in Omu's Northeast corner), but was changed to be a generic jungle picture.

The earlier version of this artwork (shown [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/06/02/new-images-revealed-from-tomb-of-annihilation/)) shows man-made ruins in the background (which were deleted in the above artwork). Also, Google labeled this as "Omu tomb of annihilation" after a reverse image [search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiuxcG82CefGlsOtzayZ4pc2azI84iTD2fTQkS2UeA0IU-pHGuNuqOa9mlXCu4B7oM2XTLXiu5B_1ilzhuuSLYnskhlc-x4es4RwkzQ2hYzVByrx9YWJeugedscxwv0LNd4B27E9gHW7SyiX6Y9ZTPxxjs1lbZALzpJeidRtnwvmymvxKwOZpcTSaH9iVPcLJ86V6GPzkII6Qg5mMZru7h0iXk32XjpbqDJeZo-wJLu9xhmf_1yyfENhcmqwNxDo4clpeX8GttMC91fDecPyHcHDayF7Tcz6hY3EQF2369KvNUyk8XI5EqTBVuTMqRdtRmn73bcc4-EVIizc6gufjPKWg9c9-05g&hl=en).

However, the Chult [FR wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Chult) page now labels this picture as simply "*The jungles of Chult*", and I believe it is now intended as generic terrain picture.

Either way: the picture is very mountainous, and thus unlikely to be a marshland or basin.